# How do prescription creature contact lenses prevent an actor from falling on the ground while running?

Tags: acting, barbarian

In an [article](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/movies/story/2022-09-11/barbarian-ending-explained-spoilers-interview-mother) about the movie [*Barbarian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarian_(2022_film)), it says the following:

> Before filming began last summer, he received advice from legendary creature performer Doug Jones, including the fine line between physical expression and nonverbal overacting and another handy pro tip: Get prescription creature contacts made, else risk biting it while chasing your co-stars through those dark tunnels.

I presume "prescription creature contacts" means contact lenses that allow the actor's eyes to appear nonhuman. I don't remember The Mother character having nonhuman eyes, but maybe I just didn't get a good enough look at them.

But what did Jones mean by "biting it"? The [definition](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/bite-it) that seems to make the most sense in the context of Jones' advice is:

> to fall and hit the ground

But why would prescription creature contact lenses make it less likely to fall than normal contact lenses or just no contact lenses at all (assuming the actor has perfect vision). Do creature contact lenses somehow make the environment seem brighter than it really is?

Comment: "biting-it" is just slang for being involved in an accident or being injured.

Comment: …which I'd have thought even more 'interesting' trying to run in Saru's shoes, whether you can see or not… https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYr2v.jpg

Comment: "(assuming the actor has perfect vision)": this is the faulty assumption.

Comment: "Bite it" refers, in my experience, to hit the ground on your stomach, often with your face (nearly) hitting the ground as though you were biting the ground.

Comment: @dbmag9 No, my faulty assumption was that Davis could have worn normal RX contact lenses for the role. Turns out he couldn't because The Mother character had lighter colored eyes than he has.

Comment: It seems here that the initial confusion is over the term "prescription". Any type of  corrective lens eyeglasses or contacts are made to a 'prescription', from the optician, just like any medicine you get from a doctor is on 'prescription'.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prescription

Comment: @Tetsujin I did not know that the actor wears corrective lenses and thus required prescription lenses. Also the word "creature" threw me off since I was pretty sure the mother did not have non-human eyes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### He is wearing cosmetic lenses

Comparing many pictures of the actor on the internet he has dark brown eyes.

[image: Harris headshot]

In the article you link, in both pictures of him made up as the monster, his irises are very pale brown.

[image: Harris being made up as the creature]

### Why the advice?

The advice is to get prescription lenses rather than just cosmetic ones.  This would require more effort and cost.

"biting-it" is just slang for being involved in an accident or picking up a serious injury (or even worse), not just in terms of falling.  In the context here, it's suggesting that performing the role without having good eyesight is dangerous.  The role involves "chasing your co-stars through dark tunnels".

Presumably Matthew Patrick Davis normally wears lenses or wears glasses.  He's just receiving advice to not perform the role without eye correction and risk injury.

Comment: That seems like really obvious advice, not exactly a "pro tip". And it's redundant too if Davis normally wears prescription contact lenses.

Comment: @pacoverflow .... you normally can't wear two sets of lenses at the same time - you can't wear a set of prescription lenses over/under the cosmetic ones.  Yeah, it does seem like obvious advice, but I can't read this any other way.

Comment: @iandotkelly That makes more sense if he needed to have nonhuman eyes for this role.

Comment: I think we can presume that when the advice was offered at least - this was what they were considering. Why on earth would the advice make any sense otherwise?  I'm sure the role required some sort of contacts (non-human or at least not normal eyes).

Comment: I edited the answer to confirm that he is indeed wearing some form of cosmetic lens for the role.

Comment: So he needed to change the color of his eyes for the role. Definitely makes sense that he'd want prescription cosmetic lenses rather than normal cosmetic lenses.

Comment: The amount of "obvious" advice that still needs to be given is enormous. Not everybody has thought up the best solution to every possible problem in every possible situation before they have to handle it - and many solutions require a long lead time.

Comment: Speaking personally, my vision without lenses is not great, but it's fine for just walking around. I might easily think, were I to be acting in a monster role that required creature lenses, that I could get by with my crappy vision on set; assuming the monster doesn't have to read any signs or make out small objects from a distance. And perhaps the people responsible for arranging for my creature lenses might think I could get by without perfect vision, to save themselves the hassle. So an experienced monster advising me to insist on prescription lenses might actually be a good idea.

Comment: @pacoverflow It's that or give the monster a pair of glasses, which would be a very different look for it...

Comment: I've never heard "biting it" to mean anything other than "falling." Is this an industry-specific use of "biting it"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- no, it is not an industry-specific meaning, just a general slang usage. It's funny, I've never heard it used in the sense of falling.  The answer is still good even if they meant "to fall" - it's clearly just advice about the lenses.

Comment: @iandotkelly Curious, where are you from?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm from the UK.

Comment: Perhaps ‘biting it’ is an elision of ‘biting the pavement’ (or ‘sidewalk’ if you're American)?

Comment: If I were an aspiring creature actor and I got any advice from Doug Jones I would treasure it and save it in a very memorable place. The amount of "obvious" advice he has about playing parts while dressed in crazy costumes probably outnumbers most other actors by a factor of 10.

Comment: Possibly biting it refers ot biting the dust, an expression meanig to die or be killed, something to be avoided.